Solutions to functional equation $\phi(x)f(x) = af(bx)$ for a given function $\phi(x)$.
For a given function $\phi(x)$, can we always find a function $f(x)$ satisfying
\begin{align}
    \phi(x)f(x) = af(bx),
\end{align}
for some $a$ and $b$?
Some examples of functions $\phi(x)$ where I have been able to find a simple solution:

If $\phi(x) = 1$, then any function $f$ will do if $a = b = 1$.
If $\phi(x) = e^x$, then $f(x) = e^{cx}$ works with $a = 1$ and $b = 1 + \frac{1}{c}$, as
\begin{align}
     \phi(x)f(x) = e^{x}e^{cx} = e^{\left(1 + \frac{1}{c}\right)cx}.
\end{align}
If $\phi(x) = \cos(x)$, then $f(x) = \sin(x)$ works with $a = \frac12$ and $b = 2$, as
\begin{align}
     \cos(x)\sin(x) = \frac12\sin(2x).
\end{align}


$f(x) = 0$ works for all $a$ and $b$. Perhaps you want to exclude that?

No matter what $a$, $b$, and $\phi$ you start witrh, the set of solutions is a vector space. In particular, the zero function is always a solution.
If $a=0$, then $f$ is a solution iff $f(x)=0$ for all $x$ with $\phi(x)\ne0$. So from now on suppose $a\ne0$.
If $b=1$, then $f$ is a solution iff $f(x)=0$ for all $x$ with $\phi(x)\ne a$.
If $b=0$, then $f$ is a solution iff either $f(0)=0$ and $f(x)=0$ for all $x$ with $\phi(x)\ne 0$; or $f(0)\ne 0$, $a=\phi(0)$, and $f(x)=a f(0)/\phi(x)$ for all $x$.
If $b=-1$, then $f$ is a solution iff $f(x)=0$ for all $x$ with $\phi(x)\phi(-x)\ne a^2$, apart from that $\phi$ is arbitrary on the nonnegative numbers and $f(-x)=\phi(x)f(x)/a$ otherwise.
If $b>1$, you can define $f$ arbitrarily on $[1,b)\cup (-b,-1]$ and the rest follows by recursion: On $[b^n,b^{n+1})$, we are then forced to have $f(x)=\phi(x/b)f(x/b)/a$ and on $[b^{-n},b^{-n+1})$, we are then forced to have $f(x)=af(bx)/\phi(x)$; similarly for negatievs, and there is always caution required when $\phi$ has zeroes.
The case $0<b<1$ can be treated similaly to $b>1$. The cases $b<-1$ and $-1<b<0$ are alo not hard, though we nowstart with arbitrary $f$ on $[1,b^2)$.
In case you wat special functions $f$ (e.g., continuous when$\phi$ is continuous), you simply need to make sure that for the initial interval $[1,b)$, the chosen function is continuous there and it lilmit as $x\to b$ matches the required value because of $f(1)$. After that, it may or may not happen that $f$ will be continuous at $0$.
